# Query Layer not found ERROR 000229

Tags: arcpy, error-000229

My code executes in three steps:

1. create FeatureLayer,
2. create QueryLayer and
3. join QueryLayer to FeatureLayer:

   ```
   arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(**{
       "in_features":features.get_dataset_fullpath(),
       "out_layer": features.get_layer_name(),
   })

   arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(**{
       "input_database":   features.get_attrib_QLD().get_workspace(),
       "out_layer_name":   features.get_attrib_QLD().get_layer_name(),
       "query"         :   features.get_attrib_QLD().get_spatial_query_definition(),
       "oid_fields"    :   features.get_attrib_QLD().get_OID_field()
   })

   arcpy.AddJoin_management (**{
        "in_layer_or_view" : features.get_layer_name(),
        "in_field"         : 'RDUWI',
        "join_table"       : features.get_attrib_QLD().get_layer_name(),
        "join_field"       : 'RDUWI',
        "join_type"        : 'KEEP_ALL'
   })
   ```

However, while executing the step three (join), the code returns:

arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000229: Cannot open permits_querylayer
Failed to execute (AddJoin),

even though the layer in question has been created in step 2.

FYI: Step two is time consuming however, I thought the execution of the next statement would wait until the previous one has returned?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am running into the same issue. I've tried some of the suggestions provided below by ew_gis, however I still get ERROR 000229.

Answer (score 1):

Query Tables only support inner joins.  You have the "join_type" set to 'KEEP_ALL', which is a union type join (outer join).  Change 'KEEP_ALL' to 'KEEP_COMMON', this will only keep matching records, an intersecting join, aka inner join.

Comment: Could you post the source of that info. At the following link I see both options: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000064000000 
Other than that, the error says that the Query layer cannot be openned (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp00000005000229), I think it does not even get to the join options part.

Comment: You would think something like this would be easy to find in writing but I cannot find anything that is concrete enough to call a valid source.  My knowledge of this is from experience and dealing with this very same workflow only to be told by my professor at the time that it was not possible.  Wish I had more for you, but that is my "source".  As for your error, rather than the get_layer_name, have you tried getting the full path?